# android fcm notification based on location

Tags: android, firebase

I'm currently working on an android app where I want users to receive notifications based on their distance from certain locations.

I'm using Firebase Cloud Messaging for notifications, but I cannot figure out how to do this.
I figure there are two possibilities:

1. Save user location on database and calculate before sending notification, but this requires lots of work and requires the user to make an account in the app to save data to the database. And how would you know whom to send to? Since a topic sends to all.
2. Send notification to all and filter out notificaion on phone before showing it. I found the onMessageReceived() function, but I cannot figure out how to stop the notification from showing here.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Since you need to know the phone's location to determine when to send an alert, you will already need code on the phone to determine that. Why would you use FCM in that case to send an alert from a server? Can't you simply show a notification locally?

Comment: The server is sending push notifications based on some events happening at specific locations for a very limited time. The phone does not know these events before it receives the notification. The app is very reliant on the user not having to check the app before a notification is shown.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure you will achieve what you want with FCM, but I would advise to go with [Google Play Services GeoFencing API](https://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing.html) that might be what you are looking for, and works very well!

Once entered in one of the regions you are monitoring (based on the radius-distance to each location) your app will be woken up, and you will be able to do whatever you want, like firing a notification, reach your backend, etc…